# Approximating distributions with normal variables

Tags: probability, statistics

> Consider independent random variables, $X_1, ..., X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

Let $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$

Then what is the approximate normal distribution of $Z + 6$?

Clearly $Z \sim N(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$

but when I do $Z + 6$, what happens to the distribution?

Comment: Adding a constant to a random variable does not change the variance, but it adds the same constant to the expected value. Adding a constant to a normally distributed random variable yields a normally distributed random variable.

Answer (score 3):

If $Z \sim N(n \mu, n \sigma^2)$, then $Z+6 \sim N(n\mu +6, \sigma^2)$.

Note that the mean is translated accordingly but the variance is not affected.

Comment: Could you help me with this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240338/if-the-magnitude-of-the-resultant-of-two-equal-vectors-is-equal-to-that-of-eithe

Comment: someone has answered the question correctly there. =)