# If the magnitude of the resultant of two equal vectors is equal to that of either vector, find the angle between them.

Tags: vectors

If the magnitude of the resultant of two equal vectors is equal to that of either vector, find the angle between them.

My Attempt:
Let $\vec {a}$ and $\vec {b}$ be two vectors such that $\|\vec {a}\|=\|\vec {b}\|$

Magnitude of Resultant:
$$=\sqrt {a^2+b^2+2ab\cos \theta}$$
$$=\sqrt {2a^2+2ab\cos \theta}$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Hint: which rhombus has a diagonal equal to the sides?

Comment: It is better to say the original two vectors $a,b$ have equal magnitudes than to say these vectors are *equal* (which we reserve for $a=b$).

Answer (score 1):

From $\|a+b\|^2=\|a\|^2$ and $\|a\|=\|b\|$ we have 
$$\|a\|^2=\|a+b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+2\langle a,b\rangle=2\|a\|^2+2\langle a,b\rangle,$$
so $\langle a,b\rangle=-\|a\|^2/2$. Hence the cosine of the angle between $a$ and $b$ using $\|a\|=\|b\|$ again is
$$\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\|a\|\|b\|}=\frac{-1}{2}.$$

Comment: How did you get $(a,b)=-|b|^2/2$?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Answer (score 1):

The resultant vector $\mathbf{OC}$ is the diagonal of the rhombus whose adjacent sides are $\mathbf{OA}, \mathbf{OB}$. Since its length is equal to either, we have an equilateral triangle $\mathbf{OBC}$. Thus the angle between the vectors is $120^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

Let,$R$ be the resultant of the sum of the two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ such that $|\vec A|=|\vec B|$.So,$$R=\sqrt{|\vec A|^2+|\vec B|^2+2|\vec A||\vec B|\cos\theta}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.So,

$$R=\sqrt{2|\vec A|^2+2|\vec A|^2\cos\theta}$$.

Now magnitude of resultant $R$ is equal to either of the vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.So,

$$|A|=\sqrt{2|\vec A|^2+2|\vec A|^2\cos\theta}$$
$$\implies|\vec A|^2=2|\vec A|^2+2|\vec A|^2\cos\theta$$
$$\implies\frac{-|\vec A|^2}{2|\vec A|^2}=\cos \theta$$
$$\implies\theta=\cos^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}$$.

Hope this helps!!